# Can there be a comma between these quotes (dialogue)?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

"Hey, look!" a boy shouted behind Tom, "he is naked."

Is that punctuation correct? To use a comma after Tom?

Comment: Have you done any research? There are some great guides to writing dialogue. https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-punctuate-dialogue

Comment: Part of the confusion here might be: If the first quote hadn't been an exclamation, it probably would have used a comma. It was "transformed" into an exclamation mark, but the second comma remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when *he said* or similar is inserted into the middle of a sentence of direct speech, it's normally followed by a comma.